# Brute Force Solver Configuration for multiple entity classes

Tags: brute-force, optaplanner

I'm running into following issue while trying to configure solver with BRUTE_FORCE for multiple entity classes:

Caused by:
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$DuplicateFieldException: Duplicate field entitySelectorConfig

Following is the configuration:

```
<solver>
  ...
  <exhaustiveSearch>
    <exhaustiveSearchType>BRUTE_FORCE</exhaustiveSearchType>
    <entitySelector>
        <entityClass>PlanningEntity_ClassA</entityClass>
    </entitySelector>
    <entitySelector>
        <entityClass>PlanningEntity_ClassB</entityClass>
    </entitySelector>
  </exhaustiveSearch>
</solver>
```

This configuration works fine if single entity is specified.
If no entity is specified, following is the exception:

The phaseConfig (ExhaustiveSearchPhaseConfig) has no entitySelector configured and because there are multiple in the entityClassSet ...

Comment: how did you solve it ??

Comment: I'm not able to solve it using BRUTE_FORCE but able to get the solution using local search.